# Searching and filtering / refining database results in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm looking for a way to search and filter a database table / Eloquent model through the query string in Laravel 4.

I have a table named `houses` with the columns named: `price`, `name`, `hasCoffeeMachine`and `hasStove`

I want the user to be able to do something like: http://example.com?name=test&hasCoffeeMachine=1

Which will get all the rows where the name is "test" and they have a coffee machine.

I want the user to be able to add URL parameters based on the filter they desire. What is the best way to account for all the possible combinations of query strings to return the correct results from the table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$houses = new House;

if(Input::get('name'))
    $houses->where('name', '=', Input::get('name'));

if(Input::get('hasCoffeeMachine'))
    $houses->where('hasCoffeeMachine', '=', Input::get('hasCoffeeMachine'));

// Keep adding more for every filter you have

// Don't do this till you are done adding filters.
$houses = $houses->get();
```

Comment: Is valid this for Laravel 4?? It´s not working for me!

Comment: Maybe try ```if (condition) ... $houses = $houses->where('column', '=', 'value')```

Comment: this solutions still valid in laravel 4.2

Comment: this will not work if hasCoffeeMachine = 0, it better if you use `Input::has('name')`

Comment: As @dynamic said, you don't seem to be able to do this when creating the object from Eloquent, you have to do this ````$houses = DB::table('house');```` Then the loop seems to work

Comment: Can you please Update this answer with some more info? How do I get `Input::get('name')`? Do you get this from a form? How? Do you post this form to the same page? I tried ten different things, can't figure it out. Also my full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799481/laravel-5-php-filter-results-with-input-value

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could build and pass in an array into the where clause https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

```
$houses = $houses->where([
    ['hasCoffeeMachine',1],
    ['price','<','1000'],
])->get();
```

You can build your array with any conditional statements.