# How to dynamically query an Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

## Synopsis

I am trying to filter my record results.  I searched google and stumbled accross [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830561/searching-and-filtering-refining-database-results-in-laravel-4).

I have a users table with **one** record that **is** active.

```
// Example 1:
$model = with(new User);
$model->where('is_active', '=', 0);

dd($model->count()); // Output: 1 (Expected: 0)

// Updated (for argument sake):
dd($model->get()->count()); // Output: 1 (Expected: 0)
```

However when I do the following I get the right result:

```
// Example 2:
dd(User::where('is_active', '=', 0)->count() ); //Output: 0 (As expected);
```

What i'm trying to do (pseudo code):

```
// Example 3:
public static function getFiltered()
{
    $model = with(new static);

    // This is obviously populated but for argument sake.
    $filters = array(
        'is_active' => 1,
    );

    foreach ( $filters as $filter => $value ) {
        $model->where($filter, '=', $value);
    }

    return $model;
}
```

I guess my question is why doesn't *example 1* work?

Bearing in mind the linked question has an accepted answer that suggests my first example should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my question is why doesn't example 1 work? Bearing in mind the linked question has an accepted answer that suggests my first example should work

No - the linked accepted answer is NOT the same as your example 1.

Your example 1 should be this:

```
$model = new User;
$newmodel = $model->where('is_active', '=', 0)->get();
dd($newmodel->count());
```

> I guess my question is why doesn't example 1 work?

Because you have applied the `where()` query, but you did not `get()` the results.

Comment: Actually, yes the linked answer is similar to my issue.  Even with `get()` I still get the same results.  The fact `get()` isn't executed is irrelevant, the problem appears to be between using a static `where` as opposed to a non static `where`.

Comment: I fixed my answer. The problem is you are doing "new Model" - which means the count will be 1 for "that" model. If you get new results and assign them to a new variable, it works as expected. I just tested it.