# Laravel 5 PHP - filter results with input value

Tags: filter, laravel-5, keyword

I have this where I get all my tournaments `$tournaments = Tournament::all();`. Now I want to let the user filter these on the go in the view... I would like to have an `<input>` where the user enters a few characters and then the results filter on tournaments that have those characters in the name.

I have found **this*** online but I dont know how to populate that `$keyword`. It would be best if the results filter after every character that is entered in the inputfield. If this is not possible, then make this a form that sends this `$keyword` to Controller and retrieves the new results **on the same page**!
* `$tournament = Tournament::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();`

How do I do this? I don't know... Please provide some code in the answer.

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you wondering how to get the input of a posted value? You can use the `Input::get()` method.

```
$keyword = Input::get('keyword');
if(isset($keyword)){
   $tournaments = Tournament::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->get();
}else{
   $tournaments = Tournament::all();
}
```

Also can also use [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) function to progressively search for results.

Comment: Now you can use when method:)